# SetTimer with unique id

Tags: windows, winapi, timer

I want to set a timer for a window, but I don't know if that window already has timers running. If it does I do not want to overwrite any of those, so I need to choose a timer id that is free. MSDN is not helpful in my case, they describe pretty much all permutations EXCEPT if you have a hwnd and not want to replace a timer.

So either if it's possible to give 0 or something as nIDEvent and have Windows create a new uniqe id automatically, or if there is some way to list currently running timers so I can avoid using any of those?

MSDN for SetTimer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The only way to auto-generate a timer ID is with a thread timer that's not bound to a particular window.

Comment: There's little point in fretting over this, just create your own window.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @Jonathan Potter said, 
you can write something like:

```
VOID CALLBACK TimerCallback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime)
{
    BOOL bRetKill = ::KillTimer(NULL, idEvent);
    // do something
}

void CSomeModel::StartTimer()
{ 
    UINT_PTR hSetTimer = ::SetTimer(NULL, 0, 1000, TimerCallback);
}
```

every time ::SetTimer is called, the idEvent ID will be unique.

Comment: Keep in mind that thread timers will not work when the thread is blocked waiting for a pop-up menu of message box to be closed. Whereas timers associated to the owner window will work just fine.